Tailwind CssSyntaxError Unknown word ">"
I'm trying to use vitest preview with tailwind
I managed to generate the css file with tailwind
tailwindcss -i ./src/styles/App.css -c tailwind.config.ts -o ./.vitest-preview/tailwind-output.css --autoprefixer

But when I launch vitest preview, I got an error :

CssSyntaxError: [postcss] Unknown word

the keyword that is not recognize is the child combinator ">"
.space-y-4 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
  --tw-space-y-reverse: 0;
  margin-top: calc(1rem * calc(1 - var(--tw-space-y-reverse)));
  margin-bottom: calc(1rem * var(--tw-space-y-reverse));
}

When I remove the ">", it's working
The test-setup.ts
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import '@fontsource/poppins'
import '@fontsource/poppins/400.css'
import '@fontsource/poppins/700.css'

import './.vitest-preview/tailwind-output.css'

vite config :
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), svgr()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        },
    },
    test: {
        include: ['**/*.test.tsx'],
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        css: true,
        setupFiles: './test-setup.ts',
        globals: true,
    },
})

EDIT
This is the component causing that (with space-y-4)
export const RadioButtons = ({ options, onChange, name = 'options', defaultChecked }: Props) => (
    <fieldset className="mt-4 space-y-4">
        {options.map((option) => (
            <div key={option.value} className="flex items-center">
                <label className="flex gap-2 items-center">
                    <input
                        id={option.value}
                        type="radio"
                        name={name}
                        defaultChecked={option.value === defaultChecked?.value}
                        className="h-4 w-4 border-gray-300 text-lime peer focus:ring-0"
                        onChange={() => onChange(option)}
                    />
                    <div className="peer-checked:text-lime font-bold">{option.label}</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        ))}
    </fieldset>
)


Are you certain the > is from your child-selector and not because it's trying to read HTML as in this case?

I'm not sure, but when I delete the > it's working. I tried to add --postcss in the cli, but not working
